# Redraw issue objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

This is my problem:

[image: Problem]

The background of the progress indicator doesn't appear to be redrawing, and it's certainely not transparent.  I'm using core animation to animate the image in the background; when I don't use core animation it looks fine.  This is the code I am using:

```
    [[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:0.25];
    [[ViewImage animator] setAlphaValue:0.5f             ];
    [[statusText animator] setAlphaValue:0.1f            ];
    [progressIndicator usesThreadedAnimation             ];
```

The progress indicator doesn't use core animation.  I have also tried removing `[progressIndicator usesThreadedAnimation];` which doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-usesThreadedAnimation is the getter for the property. You want -setUsesThreadedAnimation: to set the property.

Also, for the transparency issue, I believe you need to switch on layers for at least the progress indicator if not the parent view as well. That should fix the transparency issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I'm new to the Core Animation framework, how would I use layers?

Comment: Have you tried searching the documentation? Basic research skills are the best skills a developer can have. Failing that, there's a simple control in one of Interface Builder's inspectors for controlling the -wantsLayers property of the selected view and it's parents. Also, just FYI, layer-backed views are not Core Animation.

Comment: I have searched the documentation with no success.

Comment: How do you define success? When I type "layers" into the search field I get numerous results, the top ones being the very conceptual guides you need. There is no substitute for cracking open the documentation, settling in, and reading carefully. It takes a lot of time and study to learn this stuff. :-)